# measure memory consumption of a loaded tensorflow model in python

Tags: tensorflow, memory, model, inference

I am new to tensorflow and trying to measure how much memory a tensorflow model needs to load and do inference on a machine.

I measured the process memory before and after loading the model as below:

```
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
m1=process.memory_info().rss  # in bytes
imported = tf.saved_model.load('./predict/001')
print(list(imported.signatures.keys()))
m2=process.memory_info().rss # in bytes
print(convert_size(m2-m1))
```

however the issue is that it gives a different number each time I run it so should not be the right way to do that.
Additionally I do not know if the memory model takes after loading is the max it needs when running inference?